# Material UI version 5.10.9 - The Box component overrides the custom theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

recently I am using version 5 of Material UI in React, when I made a custom theme and added my own palette. I noticed that the Box component follows its default Material UI theme and overrides my custom theme, but the other components follow the custom theme. Can someone explain whether this behavior is Material UI itself or is there a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching several times, I realized that I was using the ThemeProvider component in @emotion/react, but I should have used the ThemeProvider component in @mui/material. By doing this, the bug related to the Box component was fixed. Thanks for the article from Sahan Amarsha.

Article link:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/lets-setup-a-react-typescript-project-with-material-ui-react-router-3d7ea8cb5596